# I'm getting this error ...in localhost/wordpress

Tags: localhost

```
( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting '&' or variable (T_VARIABLE) in C:\wamp\www\wordpress\wordpress\wp-includes\functions.php on line 1090
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  242024  {main}( )   ..\index.php:0
2   0.0010  244896  require( 'C:\wamp\www\wordpress\wordpress\wp-blog-header.php' ) ..\index.php:17
3   0.0013  265272  require_once( 'C:\wamp\www\wordpress\wordpress\wp-load.php' )   ..\wp-blog-header.php:13
```

Comment: Does it persist if you disable all the plugins and switch to a default theme? If it does, start re-activating the plugins one by one till the error recurs. That'll tell you which plugin has the issue, and whose support you need to contact.

Answer (score 1):

[Line 1090 is](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/5.7.1/wp-includes/functions.php#L1090)

```php
function add_query_arg( ...$args ) {
```

This is the variable-length argument syntax that was introduced in PHP 5.6. You're probably running an older version of PHP than that.

Since version 5.2 WordPress requires at least PHP 5.6.20, but currently recommends 7.4+. See [the requirements page](https://wordpress.org/about/requirements/) or the readme in the download.